# traverse backwards, return the outer dictionary value in case match found in inner dictionary for search value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary where value contains another dicitonary, I need to search for a string in inner dictionary and if its matches need to return the value of outer dictionary first key.

here is list as follow :

```
lst=[{'value': 'value1', 'Characteristic': {'ID': 'searchstr1'}},
     {'value': 'value2', 'Characteristic': {'ID': 'searchstr2'}}, 
     {'value': 'value3', 'Characteristic': {'ID': 'searchstr3'}}
     , {'value': 'value4', 'Characteristic': {'ID': 'searchstr4'}}]
```

and search string is

```
search_str="searchstr3"
```

so in that case it should return the

```
value3 as result .
```

I tried by looping through the list and then getting each dictionary item but not sure how to travers back once find the desired value.

here is my code what i tired so far :

```
def find_value():
    for dicts in lst:
        current = dicts["value"]
        for k,v in dicts.items():
            #print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))        
            if isinstance(v, dict):                
                if v['ID']==search_str:
                    break 
        return current
```

Comment: `for dicts in lst: current = dicts["value"]`?

Comment: dict is unordered structure - you could have a key with matched string as a 1st key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your simple case it's not about the 1st key but a particular key `'value'` - just return the needed value immediately:

```
lst = [{'value': 'value1', 'Characteristic': {'ID': 'searchstr1'}},
     {'value': 'value2', 'Characteristic': {'ID': 'searchstr2'}},
     {'value': 'value3', 'Characteristic': {'ID': 'searchstr3'}},
     {'value': 'value4', 'Characteristic': {'ID': 'searchstr4'}}]
search_str = "searchstr3"

def find_value(lst, search_str):
    for d in lst:
        for k,v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict) and v['ID'] == search_str:
                return d['value']
    return None

print(find_value(lst, search_str))   # value3
```